Can we parameterize jQuery ajax call for inserting data to database?
This is my simple code for inserting data to database and it's working fine. Table name is AccountMaster
function Insert() {
    var Value = {};
    Value.Id = $("[id*=hdnId]").val();
    Value.AccountName = $("[id*=txtAccountName]").val();
    Value.Catagory = $("[id*=txtCatagory]").val();
    Value.CatagorySr = $("[id*=hdnCatagorySr]").val();
    Value.HeadName = $("[id*=hdnHeadName]").val();
    Value.HeadId = $("[id*=hdnHeadId]").val();
    Value.BalanceSheetSr = $("[id*=hdnBalanceSheetSr]").val();
    Value.AccountTypeName = $("[id*=txtAccountTypeName]").val();
    Value.AccountTypeId = $("[id*=hdnAccountTypeId]").val();
    Value.AccountTypeSr = $("[id*=hdnAccountTypeSr]").val();
    Value.Sr = $("[id*=txtSr]").val();
    Value.AccountCode = $("[id*=hdnAccountCode]").val();
    Value.OpeningBalance = $("[id*=txtOpeningBalance]").val();
    Value.Nature = $("[id*=ddlNature]").val();
    Value.ClosingBalance = $("[id*=txtClosingBalance]").val();
    Value.PrevYearIE = $("[id*=txtPrevYearIE]").val();
    Value.TINNo = $("[id*=txtTINNo]").val();
    Value.GSTNo = $("[id*=txtGSTNo]").val();
    Value.Remark = $("[id*=txtRemark]").val();
    Value.Address = $("[id*=txtAddress]").val();
    Value.EntryBy = '<%=Session["Name"]%>';
    Value.ChangedBy = '<%=Session["Name"]%>';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AccountMaster.aspx/InsertUpdate",
        data: '{Value: ' + JSON.stringify(Value) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Saved Successfully");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

Above code shows that every time I have to add fields to Value one by one. If I have more than 100 fields in a database table I have to add it one by one which is very painful sometimes. So I decided to parameterize that section by collecting all the fields from database table and add them through loop like this...
function Insert(FormName, DivName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "" + FormName + ".aspx/GetData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var Records = xml.find("Table");
            if (Records.length > 0) {
                var Main = {};
                $.each(Records, function () {
                    var record = $(this);
                    var ColName = record.find("Column_name").text();   //Getting Column names from database
                    var ColValue = GetColumnsValue(ColName, DivName);  // getting columns value in webform.
                    Main.ColName = ColValue; // adding columns value to Main, this line is not working                     
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "" + FormName + ".aspx/Insert",
                    data: "{MainValues: " + JSON.stringify(Main) + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (d) {
            alert(d.responseText);
        }
    });
}

As usual above method thinks ColName is the field of database table.
And here is my GetData code in c#
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            using (SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                using (SqlConnection Con = Connections.Create())
                {
                    Cmd.Connection = Con;
                    Cmd.CommandText = "GetColumnList_pro".Trim();
                    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Option", "GetColumnList".Trim());
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Table", "DummyTable".Trim());
                    using (SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        using (DataSet Ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            Con.Open();
                            Adp.SelectCommand = Cmd;
                            Adp.Fill(Ds);
                            return Ds.Geml();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


But still you need to map the column name according to to your databse table entity name which would different as well. Because, record.find("Column_name").text() you are getting should be same as database entity name.

In addition, you might need to pull the dynamic table and column name before insert anything like string tableName = "YourTableName"; string sqlInsert = $"INSERT INTO {tableName} ({string.Join(", ", columnNames)})

Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you do not want to be voted down, DO AS IS ASKED. In this case, what is the question? If you are asking if your working code is a good idea, then it is for codereview and not stackoverflow.  If you have an error, explain what the error is and what you tried to fix it. For example you did not post GetColumnsValue. It could very well be an X/Y problem, hard to tell
